# React getstream.io authentication problem

Tags: reactjs, authentication, getstream-io, getstream-chat

We got an error in stream authentication while login as a register user. I think there is a problem in stream configuration because I double check my code there was no problem.

[image]

We try to eanble and disable all the options like "development" and "production" but didn't get any response.